# Protocol for proof of knowledge of $l$-th root

Tags: rsa, group-theory, number-theory, hardness-assumptions

Assume we have Group G in which the adaptive root assumption holds. 
This assumption states that if we choose an element $w$ and after that, if we receive a prime value $l$ it is hard to find the $u$ such that: $u^l = w$

Now suppose I want to prove that I know a $l\text{-}th$ root of an element $w$ without revealing it. (I don't want to reveal $u$). Is there any protocol for this?

Comment: The Schnorr identification and signature protocol may be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The immediately obvious solution would be this simple cut-and-choose protocol:

- Prover: selects a random value $v$ and sends the value $y = v^\ell$
- Verifier: selects and sends a random bit $b$
- Prover: if $b=0$, sends the value $t_0=v$.  If $b=1$, sends the value $t_1=vu$
- Verifier: if $b=0$, then verify that $t_0^\ell = y$.  If $b=1$, then verify that $t_1^\ell = y w$

The standard zero knowledge logic works - if the prover knows a $y$ value for which he knows both correct responses $t_0$ and $t_1$, then (assuming that inverses are also easy to compute) he can recover the value $u$ (hence, if he succeeds with this protocol a number of times, then the probability of success without him knowing $u$ is minimal).  And, only one of the answers does not give any information to the verifier.

Comment: Do you know also a solution that could be made non-intereractive?

Comment: @JanMoritz: if you don't mind long non-interactive proof, the standard way to convert a cut-and-choose protocol into noninteractive works (the prover publishes a long series ($n$ values) of $y$ values $y_1, y_2, …, y_n$; he computes the values $b_1, b_2, …, b_n$ based on the hash of all those $y$ values, and then the series of values $t_{i, b_i}$ values computed as above.  The verifier then hashes the $y$ values to recreate the $b_i$ values, and then individually verified the $t$ values.  This is chatty (the proof might be circa a megabyte), but it works.

Comment: I added a new question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81094/proving-the-knowlege-of-e-th-root-in-an-non-interactive-way Unfortunately the size of the proof does matter as well :/

Comment: I edited the question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81094/proving-the-knowlege-of-e-th-root-in-an-non-interactive-way so that it now contains a proposal on how to do it with the GQ protocol.

Answer (score 1):

"Deep coins" protocol by Guillou and Quisquater:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45961-8_11.pdf

Comment: With this protocol, a cheater has a probability $1/\ell$ of being able to fool a single pass (by guessing $d$ beforehand); with the cut-and-choose, they have a $0.5$ probability.  For large $\ell$, this is much better; for $\ell = 3$, well, it's a lot closer...